# Где ошибка?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double dis, light, delay, delay_min;

    dis = 34000000.0;
    light = 186000.0;
    delay = dis / light;
    cout << 'Delay is ' << delay << ' seconds.n';
    delay_min = delay / 60;
    cout << 'It is ' << delay_min << ' minutes';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что хотите получите и что не так выходит? С точки зрения синтаксиса, вроде, все правильно.

Comment: да, точно)

Answer (score 2):

Строки должны быть заключены в двойные кавычки:

```
cout<<"Delay is "<< delay<<" seconds.\n";
```